# How to expand a preprocessor directive outside where it was called

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am experimenting with compile time enum assertions and I came up with following code:

```
template<int Value>
inline constexpr bool isValueUsed(){
    return false;
}

class BaseEnum{
private:
    constexpr BaseEnum(int value): _value(value){
    }
public:
    template<int value>
    constexpr static BaseEnum CreateEnum() {
        static_assert(!isValueUsed<value>(), "The value is already used");
        return BaseEnum(value);
    }

    constexpr BaseEnum& operator=(const BaseEnum& other){
        return *this;
    }

    // public for testing purposes
    int _value;
};

namespace BaseEnumValues {
    constexpr BaseEnum Default = BaseEnum::CreateEnum<0>();
}

#include <iostream>

int main(){
    // Tests Definition
    BaseEnum baseEnum1 = BaseEnumValues::Default;
    BaseEnum baseEnum2 = BaseEnum::CreateEnum<1>();
    // Should fail to compile
    // BaseEnum baseEnum3 = BaseEnum::CreateEnum<1>();

    std::cout << "BaseEnum1: " << baseEnum1._value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "BaseEnum2: " << baseEnum2._value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to create specializations of the template each time `CreateEnum<>` is called, however I have no idea how to do that, I implemented a preprocessor directive that will expand to the specialization, but I call it inside the function so it will expand there, is there a way to expand the directive outside of where it was called?

```
#define DEFINE_ENUM_VALUE(value) \
    template<> \
    inline constexpr bool isValueUsed<value>(){ \
        return true; \
    }

template<int value>
    constexpr static BaseEnum CreateEnum() {
        static_assert(!isValueUsed<value>(), "The value is already used");
        DEFINE_ENUM_VALUE(value) // This should be expanded elsewhere in the code
        return BaseEnum(value);
    }
```

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: C++ just doesn't work like this,on a fundamental level. Setting aside the syntax issue there's nothing to prevent different translation units from defining the same enum value. The most that can be done here would be to concoct something that causes an ODR-use violation, but that will result in a link failure, not a compilation failure.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ODR will be attached to a specific variable but not a value, I want to allow the users to create new variables but with distinct values (or take a reference from an existing one). I want to achieve this using compile-time validations. Are you sure it's not possible? Maybe I am just using the wrong approach?

Comment: Suppose you and I each compile a .cpp file with an enum. How is the compiler to know - at compile time - if the values are different?

Comment: @BoP Mmmm, imagine I have BaseEnum.hpp and enum1.cpp and enum2.cpp each one will create BaseEnums, if all specializations of isValueUsed() are inside BaseEnum.hpp then won't the compiler have access to those in both files?

Comment: Suppose `enum1.cpp` and `enum2.cpp` do define the same value. You seem to be saying that, if `enum1.cpp` is compiled on its own, it should succeed. And if `enum2.cpp` is compiled on its own, it should succeed. But if `enum2.cpp` is compiled after `enum1.cpp` has been compiled, then it should somehow magically fail - even though no file used as an input to the compilation has changed. In what way do you imagine the information about previous compilation sessions would travel to the subsequent ones?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Mmmm, I have no idea why the conversations turn out like this. No, the compiler can't know, and I did not say that. Do you have any advice on how to approach the initial problem?